# How to avoid inconsistency due to concurrent queries in Big Query

Tags: database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to ensure that multiple concurrent reads and writes in Big Query do not suffer from inconsistency?

I don't think there is a 'transaction' mechanism for Big Query tables. Is it? How are such scenarios usually handled?

I am using Java API for querying and writing data in the Big Query.

Any pointers will help. Thanks.

Comment: Which APIs are you using? Are you issuing DML queries, streaming inserts, or regular queries with a destination table set?